# assignment incompatible pointer type (WARNING)

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

The problem is every time I try to submit this code this message shows up:

> assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

The warning is caused by  aux=q;
How should I make them compatible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a, b, c, d;
}
t_cuatro;

void order(t_cuatro * q);

int main()
{
    t_cuatro x = {5,6,2,8};
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d);
    ordenar(&x);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d);
    return 0;
}

void order(t_cuatro  *q)
{
    int * aux;

    int aux2;

    int i,j;

    aux=q;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(*(aux + i)>*(aux + j))
               {
                   aux2 = *(aux+i);
                   *(aux+i) = *(aux+j);
                   *(aux+j) = aux2;

               }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: One of them is a pointer to `int` the other one is a pointer to a `struct` - it shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to change them to be of the same type

Comment: Also the entire logic (the nested `for` loops) is bordering on *undefined behavior* as you are working on a `struct`, not an array of `int`

Comment: I know that one is int and other one is a pointer to a struct,but the problem is that I don't know how to make both of them compatible without changing the entire program,beacuse the program itself works okay,but that warning is bothering me ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int *` and `struct t_cuatro *` are not compatible. You can't "make" them compatible.

It looks like you are attempting to sort the contents in a struct...but you haven't actually used the members in `order()`. I suggest you use an *array* (instead of four variables: a, b, c, and d):

```
typedef struct
{
    int arr[4];
}
t_cuatro;
```

Then in `order()` you can assign it to an `int *`:

```
void order(t_cuatro  *q)
{
    int *aux = q->arr;
    /* remove the assignment aux = q; */
 ....
```

Print the array as:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof x.arr/sizeof x.arr[0]; ++i)
printf("%d ", x.arr[i]);
```

Comment: Good answer.  I especially approve of "You can't 'make' them compatible", which I was just about to say myself.